# Attempt to read property "id" on null LARAVEL8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, web-development-server

I'm new to laravel and I'm learning it from laracast.
Here is my problem, I'm creating a comment form and it's php code looks like this:

```
<section class="col-span-8 col-start-5 mt-10 space-y-6">
    <!-- Post form -->
    <form method="POST" action="/post/{{ $post->slug }}/comments" class="border border-gray-200 p-6 rounded-xl">
        @csrf
        <header class="flex items-center">
            <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/100?id={{ auth()->id() }}" alt="" width="40" height="40" class="rounded-full">
            <h2 class="ml-3 ">Want to participate?</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="mt-6">
            <textarea class="w-full text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring"
             name="body"  
             cols="30" rows="10"
              placeholder="Quick,think of something to say!" ></textarea>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 text-white uppercase font-semi-bold text-xs py-2 px-10 rounded-2xl hover:bg-blue-600">Post</button>
        </div>
```

this is the corresponding route:

```
Route::post('post/{post:slug}/comments',[PostCommentsController::class, 'store']);
```

Controller:, and I suspect there could be something wrong here `'user_id'=> request()->user()->id`, and I tried numerous ways for this approach like `auth()->id, Auth::user()->id`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;


class PostCommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Post $post){

        
        request()->validate([
            'body'=>'required'
        ]);

        $post->comments()->create([
            'user_id'=> request()->user()->id,
            'body' => request('body')
        ]);

        return back();
    }
}
```

and this the migration table for comment

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('post_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
```

migration table for post:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('category_id');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('excerpt');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
});
```

If I click on post button I get the above error,tried my best to solve this problem but I couldn't. Can someone help me what's wrong with my code ?. My question may look naive as I'm new to stackoverflow community

Comment: Error Messages: Normally come with a line number and a bit more information that that. Always give us the complete error message. And indicate in the code Which line has the error, specially if its line 1000 and you dont show all 1000 lines

Comment: I suspect something wrong with controller code but I tried numerous ways on that, but coudn't figure out what part I'm missing that's why I posted related codes.

Comment: The error might appear if during `request()->user()->id`  the part `request()->user()` is null i.e. there's no authenticated user

Comment: @apokryfos So how do I resolve that?

Comment: `Route::post('post/{post:slug}/comments',[PostCommentsController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth')` this will prevent you from running that route if you are not signed in.

Comment: Yup I was looking for this and poor me just forgot to log in and thanks for other way around for telling how to do it without signing in.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for controller

```
class PostCommentsController extends Controller
{
public function store(Post $post){

    
    request()->validate([
        'body'=>'required'
    ]);

    $post->comments()->create([
        'user_id'=> optional(auth()->user())->id,
        'body' => request('body')
    ]);

    return back();
}
}
```

user must logged in

Comment: If I do this I'm getting {Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$id} this error

Comment: The user may not be logged in.
check this:
auth()->id();

Comment: {'user_id'=> optional(auth()->user())->id}  used this and I get {Attempt to read property "id" on null}  this error

Comment: you are getting this error , because user is not login.
First, the user must be logged in and then use this code.

Answer (score 0):

first you must logged in

and in your route you must define your middleware if you are trying to get authenticated user's id like this

```
Route::post('post/{post:slug}/comments',[PostCommentsController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth');
```

after that in your method/function inside controller use 'Request' class(not model class name) when you try to retrieve input from form

Laravel's 'Illuminate\Http\Request' class provides an object-oriented way to interact with the current HTTP request being handled by your application as well as retrieve the input, cookies, and files that were submitted with the request.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;  //don't forget this
    class PostCommentsController extends Controller
    {
    public function store(Request $request){
    
        
        request()->validate([
            'body'=>'required'
        ]);
    
        $post->comments()->create([
            'user_id'=> auth()->user()->id,
            'body' => request('body')
        ]);
    
        return back();
    }
    }
```